# Yii2 using ActiveQuery that uses sub-query on same Model

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a `Comments` table that have `parent_id` foreign key that points to itself to enable threaded comment.

```
Comments
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
parent_id INT UNSIGNED NULL
comment TEXT NOT NULL
created_time DATETIME NOT NULL
```

The original `ActiveQuery` is like this

```
class CommentActiveQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery {
    public function andWhereIsNotRemoved() {
        return $this->andWhere(['isRemoved' => Comment::STATUS_IS_NOT_REMOVED]);
    }

    public function andWhereParentIdIs($parentId) {
        return $this->andWhere(['parentId' => $parentId]);
    }

    public function orderByNewestCreatedTime() {
        return $this->orderBy(['createdTime' => SORT_DESC]);
    } 
}
```

Now I want to sort the comments by the newest active reply.

The query is basically like this

```
SELECT `*`, `last_reply_time` 
    FROM `Comments` 
    WHERE `parent_id` IS NULL 
    ORDER BY `last_reply_time` DESC;
```

I'm thinking the `last_reply_time` is a subquery

```
SELECT MAX(created_time) 
   FROM `Comments` 
   WHERE `parent_id` = :something
```

How to build this using the `CommentActiveQuery` above. The farthest I can get is like this

```
public function orderByNewestActiveChildCreatedTime() {
    return $this->addSelect([
            'last_reply_time' => $subQuery
           ])->orderBy(['last_reply_time' => SORT_DESC]);
}
```

With what should I replace the `$subQuery` variable above? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

```
$subQuery = new \yii\db\Query();
$subQuery->select(["max(subQ.created_time)"]);
$subQuery-> from('comments subQ');
$subQuery->where([
    'parent_id' => $parentId
]);

$query = new \yii\db\Query();
$query->select([
    'C.*',
    $subQuery
]);
$query->from('Comments C');
$query->andWhere(
    'parent_id is Null'
);


$command = $query->createCommand();

 /*

   Printing the command will result following sql  with $parentId = 1     

   SELECT
        `C`.*, (
         SELECT
            max(subQ.created_time)
         FROM
            `comments` `subQ`
         WHERE
             `parent_id` =: qp0
         ) AS `1`
    FROM
         `Comments` `C`
    WHERE
         parent_id IS NULL

*/

print_r($command->sql);
```

> I am not sure about  ORDER BY `last_reply_time` DESC; Assuming `last_reply_time` is db table attribute  and is different from the subquery. You can simply add orderBy in the query by doing $query->orderBy('last_reply_time DESC')

I hope this would be helpful to you.Cheers :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer, because Query and ActiveQuery are different.

According to this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9720 subqueries with ActiveQuery are still impossible.